# How can I set the default Node.js version with nvm?

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, npm, nvm

I'm using [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to manage my Node.js versions. In my projects, I have *.nvmrc* files in the project root. When I run `nvm use`, I get the Node.js version needed for the project.

This is all working great, **but** when I open up a new console window, at first I always have a very old Node.js version set automatically.

Running `node -v` gives me `6.9.5`.

What's really annoying is that my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) runs pre-commit hooks when I use its VCS commit dialog using this old Node.js version, which makes unit tests and the commit fail.

**How can I make it so that a specific version of Node.js is set as default?**

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use the command `nvm alias` to set the `default` version you would like to use, for example:

```
nvm install 10.17.0
nvm alias default 10.17.0
```

Comment: Do you mean `nvm install 10.17.0`?

Comment: When I run "nvm alias default 10.17.0", it just gives me a list of available options... it just doesn't seem to do anything  (and my "ng -v" continues to use the wrong, older, version of node.js)   Has something changed with nvm ?

Comment: It looks like windows users can't do this: https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/issues/461

Comment: @MikeGledhill I was also wondering about it, until I found out that I misspelled "alias" like "alies" ))